# If there are two ng-click directives on a tag, what will happen?

Tags: angularjs

One 'correct' way to specify multiple actions within an ng-click is to separate each one with a semi-colon, however I've come across code that specifies two ng-click directives on the same tag. Will both sets of the ng-click instructions be carried out, will this cause an error, or will only one or other of the ng-click instructions be executed?

Comment: What about testing yourself, it will be faster.

Comment: Because I want there to be a SO question that everyone can reference, so they don't have to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have many ng-clicks on a tag, only the first one will get executed.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CookieCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.print1 = function () {
       alert("first");
    }
     $scope.print2 = function () {
       alert("second");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">    
    <div id="button-holder" ng-controller="CookieCtrl">
        <button ng-click="print1()" ng-click="print2()">Bump!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also have many functions executed on ng-click using a **`;`** separated.
**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CookieCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.print1 = function () {
       alert("first");
    }
     $scope.print2 = function () {
       alert("second");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">    
    <div id="button-holder" ng-controller="CookieCtrl">
        <button ng-click="print1();print2();">Bump!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```